# Saving using a barcode scan as file name

Tags: arrays

What I’m trying to get is a pop up that says scan job number that disappears when number is scanned  then another pop up that says scan material tested that also disappears

Both pieces of data then become the file name with an underscore  between the two pieces of data

EG JN1106846_F114-CHT-00343

Another pop up that displays the data for the user to confirm it’s correct.
If yes, saves to a preset path if no loops back to the beginning

I’ve nearly got it working, the bits I’m struggling with are

The variable file name and getting the underscore in it ( I thought maybe copying the text from the message box would do it but I can’t seem to do it)

Accepting the scan data when the correct number of characters have been entered

And handling multiple files with the same name. I wanted to time stamp them but colons stop it from saving

Any suggestions??

Sub tt()

Dim inputData As String

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

inputData = InputBox("Scan Job Number:", "Scan it you slag!")
If inputData <> "" Then
  scan = inputData
End If

inputData = InputBox("Scan part number:", "Scan it you slag!")
If inputData <> "" Then
partnum = inputData
End If

Ret_Type = MsgBox(scan & "_" & partnum & "_" & Now(), vbYesNo, "Filename Correct?")




Select Case Ret_Type

Case 6
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("M:\Quality\Public\ManufacturingHistory\RoughnessTestingResults\VarableFilename " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YY") & ".xlsx")



Case 7
Call tt

End Select
```

End Sub

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review the [guide to asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Typically, a good question includes examples of what you have tried yourself.  Work on coming up with a solution and then post here with code examples if you run into problems or want more clarification.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Logan, fair comment I’ve just updated it

Answer (score 0):

First you should store your file name in a variable right after your created it like so :

```
Dim filename As String = scan & "_" & partnum & "_" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YY")
Ret_Type = MsgBox(filename, vbYesNo, "Filename Correct?")
```

So you'll have the `Datetime` stored and kept as soon as you capture it, else if the user takes 1 hour before clicking Ok in your MsgBox and you set again a `Now()` during your saving, the latest date will be taken instead of the first one you generated one hour ago.

Also, it is never recommended to programmatically put a space character in a filename. You should replace them with an underscore. Try this line of code to save your xlsx file:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("M:\Quality\Public\ManufacturingHistory\RoughnessTestingResults\" & filename & ".xlsx")
```

Comment: Hi Jimmy, made perfect sense after you pointed it out.. convert it into a text string and make the string the variable.. thanks for your help works now.  Sam

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Logan and Jimmy..

If anyone else is looking for a similar function, the final code is below 
I would recommend using a user form over a  inputBox as I couldn’t get the inputBox to auto accept based on number of characters entered

Sub tt()

Dim inputData As String

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

inputData = InputBox("Scan Job Number:", "Scan it you slag!")
If inputData <> "" Then
  scan = inputData
End If

inputData = InputBox("Scan part number:", "Scan it you slag!")
If inputData <> "" Then
partnum = inputData
End If
```

Dim filename As String
    filename = scan & "*" & partnum & "*" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YY-HH-MM-SS")

```
Ret_Type = MsgBox(scan & "_" & partnum & "_" & Now(), vbYesNo, "Filename Correct?")


Select Case Ret_Type

Case 6

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("M:\Quality\Public\ManufacturingHistory\RoughnessTestingResults\" & filename & ".xls")

Case 7
Call tt

End Select
```

End Sub